Send Later Emails Don't Link to Record
Problem
When I use Send Later from a Salesforce Record page, the resulting emails are not automatically linked to the Record (eg. Lead or Contact). I'd like to know if there's a way to Send Later without tracking pixels, and still automatically get associations between the email and Record?
Context:
I don't use (or want to use) tracking pixels. When I send directly (with no delay) from Salesforce, my emails are linked appropriately: I'm guessing this is because Salesforce also sends them (automatically) via bcc to a special Salesforce email address. I don't see that address on the Send Later emails.
More Details:

I'm using Lightning and am admin.
I send emails from Salesforce using the Gmail integration (emails are sent via SMTP from my Gmail account).
I use EAC but I've turned off Track External Emails because I don't want tracking pixels in my emails.

